# using echo statement after dynamic HTML

Tags: php, html

Here's the problem, I am trying to echo a statement or an array after dynamically generated HTML, and unfortunately the thing that i want to echo goes above the HTML, is there any way to echo it after that dynamic HTML or work around?

Code:

```
<a href="index.php?id=do_something">Link 1</a>
<a href="index.php?id=do_something_else">Link 2</a>

if(isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] == "do_something") { 
   $html = "dynamic html generate";
   echo $html;
   //after this im using foreach
   foreach($array as $item) { echo $item . "<br />"; }
}
```

As I click one of these two , dynamically generated HTML shows up. Now for example I have an array:

```
$array = array("error1", "error2");
```

All the generated PHP goes above the dynamic HTML :/.
How should i fix it so that i can echo all of this array below the dynamic HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code. If something appears outside of where you expect it, it's often a result of invalid/incorrect HTML. (like trying to make a `<div>` as a child of `<table>`)

Comment: We still need more code than this - we need to see the context in which that `foreach` loop appears, inside the other HTML, and where you _expect_ it to appear.

Comment: If you don't want your echos to be output within the HTML, then outside your closing `</body></html>` tags for example, perform your echos there? then it'll be displayed at the bottom

Comment: are you sure that your html is only a string "dynamic html generate" ? do you use any javascript code for add something to your page ?

Comment: its not just "dynamic html generate", it looks up a function through an object and gets the specific code and stores it inside $html.

Comment: i think the problem is in how you interact with your object , your code here work without problem if you use the string above, please we need to know how your object function works. add more details please

Comment: Thank you all of you I actually found a way out and its working gracefully now.

Answer (score 0):

Use buffering with [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

```
ob_start();
// dynamic html code generate
$dynamic_html = ob_get_clean();

echo $dynamic_html;

// your code

echo $dynamic_html;
```

Comment: This is a hack. Once the OP posts code, the solution is likely to be a lot simpler than manipulating the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you missed some closing tags (most likely `</table>`) in the dynamic html. Thats why the later generated echo gets displayed at the top.

Example (Note the missing closing table):

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr><td>TableText</td></tr>";

echo "I should be bellow the table, but going to the top.";


?>
```

will produce:

```
I should be bellow the table, but going to the top. 
TableText
```

Comment: im not using a <table>, its getting echoed inside <div>

Comment: @Abhinav This was just an example. There are various tag errors, that can cause that behaviour. If the Dynamic HTML would be correct, the later output would be, where it should be displayed.